# How to include Images in a word doc by using a field that references a second word doc that in turn has fields which reference the images?

Tags: ms-word, field

I'll give an example with two images. In reality I have to do this several times with thousands of images each time.

So I have two images on my desktop and I open a word file and I insert those two images using fields like so:

```
 { INCLUDEPICTURE "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\image_a" }
```

and

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\image_a" }
```

I then save this word document as `two_images_test.docx`. In a new document I want to create a field with the path to `two_images_test.docx` in order to be able to display the two images in this new document. I figured this would do it:

```
  { INCLUDEPICTURE "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\two_images_test.docx" }
```

but alas, it doesn't work and I get an error message saything that the linked image cannot be displayed bla bla bla... Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `INCLUDETEXT` instead of `INCLUDEPICTURE` for your second file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link two or more Word documents together, you should use INCLUDETEXT fields, not INCLUDEPICTURE fields. If you want to link a specific range, bookmark that ranges in the source document and specify the bookmark in the INCLUDETEXT field.

For more on the INCLUDETEXT field, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-includetext-field-1c34d6d6-0de3-4b5c-916a-2ff950fb629e

To use INCLUDETEXT fields and INCLUDEPICTURE fields with relative paths, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html